# How to generate usage documentation for custom Processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created several custom NiFi processors, but have been unable to get usage documentation to be generated.  'Usage' documentation refers to right clicking on a processor and selecting 'Usage', which should bring up documentation about that specific processor. The documentation panel is displayed, but none of my custom processors are present.

I used several NiFi documentation tags on my custom processor classes including several Read/Written attributes. The code compiles and unit tests without any issues.  The build reports

> [INFO] Generating documentation for NiFi extensions in the NAR...

According to the developer [guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#advanced-documentation) documentation is supposed to automatically be generated.

I also tried creating an `additionalDetails.html` file and putting it in the nar according the documentation.

> This file should exist within a directory whose name is the fully-qualified name of the Processor, and this directory’s parent should be named docs and exist in the root of the Processor’s jar.

However, that broke NiFi and I found this in the logs.

```
        === End Processor types ===
2019-08-16 15:16:36,100 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.generate(DocGenerator.java:62)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:158)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:72)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:297)
2019-08-16 15:16:36,100 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
```

I'm using the standard `nifi-nar-maven-plugin` to generate the nar file.
Here's a snippet of my `pom.xml`file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
  <artifactId>nifi-mylib</artifactId>
  <packaging>nar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.3</version>
  <name>nifi-mylib</name>

  <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <nifi.version>1.9.2</nifi.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
          <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
          <version>${nifi.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
              <artifactId>nifi-nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.1</version>
              <extensions>true</extensions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.15</version>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The generated .nar (without the `additionalDetails.html` file) load correctly and appear in the list of processors.  It's just the Usage documentation that I can't get to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get some help on the NiFi email list.

The nar has to contain a jar with the processors. This explains how to setup the maven project structure:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions#MavenProjectsforExtensions-ExampleProcessorBundleStructure